# running a set up file in a batch as an admin?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I created a batch to run specific commands, the code looks like this:

```
cd  D:\projects\Project Stress Test\signed one\com0com\x64
setupc
pause
```

what i want is to run the `setupc` file as an admin?

i tried `runas /user:<Name>\administrator` commands but it didnt work.

is there any easy way to do that?

Comment: Don't you need quotes around that path? It has spaces in it.

Comment: Make sure you're using [runas](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true) correctly.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, actually the path works and i can run the file from the batch. but what i am trying to do is to run as an administrator

Comment: Well what does "it didn't work" mean? `runas /user:YOURHOSTNAME\Administrator setupc` should work,

Comment: @Blorgbeard: for cd command, it will work. it probably assimilates all the argv's to form a single path. I have, however, not tested it against 2 consecutive spaces, like "project<space><space>stress<space>test"

Comment: You have to enter password manually to 'runas' command. If you are trying to do it in automated way, it will not work as is. For that, try scheduled task or such option.

Comment: @anishsane, i managed to run as admin but it can't accept the password in the command line. i tried to enter the password manually but still no luck.. maybe i m using wrong syntax, here is the code: `runas /noprofile/user:MyPc\Administrator setupc 123`

Comment: try running runas manually from cmd & post here what error it throws.

Comment: 123 is password? 2 notes: you cannot enter password as command line arguments to runas. You have to manually enter it, or use linux's `expect` like utility (search for `sanur.exe`, a third party code, I haven't not tested for viruses.) Second note: If 123 is the argument to your program, you need to quote command+argument as a single argument to runas. Try `runas /?` on cmd.exe.

Comment: @anishsane, when i used `runas /user:Liban\Administrator setupc` it prompts me to enter password but it doesn't accept any input, basically i can't write the password, so there is Logon Failure.
i will try the `sanur.exe`

Comment: @liban it is accepting input, it just doesn't echo it back at you. Type the password and press enter. It won't show on screen, but it will work (if you type it correctly ;)

Comment: @Blorgbeard i am sure i am entering the correct password, it is very short actaully..
by the way, i solved the problem by running the bat file as an admin in a c# code. 
thanks for ur suggestions

Comment: @Liban I mean that `runas` does not *appear* to accept input (you won't see anything happen when you type your password), but it actually does work. Anyway, glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make the entire script run at admin level.  Here is a batch function I use in my scripts.

```
@echo off
call :Admin xReturn true 1
echo.%xReturn%
goto End

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:Admin <Return> [Needed] [Success]
:: Check for Administrator privileges and request privileges if needed.
:: NOTE: This will restart the script with Admin privs if Needed is set to true.
:::: Usage: call :Admin xReturn true
:: Return success value, if user is Admin. Default `true` if Success not set.
setlocal
set xVBUAC=%Temp%\AdminUAC.vbs
set xSuccess=true
if not "%~3"=="" set xSuccess=%~3

:: Check for Access
::net session >nul 2>&1
>nul 2>&1 "%SystemRoot%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SystemRoot%\system32\config\system"
if %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 set xAdmin=%xSuccess%

:: Execute UAC
if /i not "%xAdmin%"=="%xSuccess%" if not "%~2"=="" if /i "%~2"=="true" (
  echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%xVBUAC%"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%xVBUAC%"
    if exist "%xVBUAC%" (
        "%xVBUAC%"
        rem if %ErrorLevel% EQU 5 echo Access Denied. Launching UAC.
        del "%xVBUAC%"
    )
)
endlocal & if not "%~1"=="" set "%~1=%xAdmin%"
goto :eof

:End
```