# Run reg command in cmd (bat file)?

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry, cmd

I'm trying to run this reg code in cmd (bat file), but I couldn't make it work. Where am I doing wrong?

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Control Panel]
"HomePage"=dword:00000001
```

It works if I make it a reg file and double click.

Bat file code (this doesn't work, no errors):

```
@echo off
reg add "HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Control Panel" /V HomePage /T REG_DWORD /F /D 1
```

Comment: Is it printing out any errors? Add `pause` as the last line of the bat file.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You will probably get an UAC prompt when importing the reg file. If you accept that, you have more rights.

Since you are writing to the 'policies' key, you need to have elevated rights. This part of the registry protected, because it contains settings that are administered by your system administrator.

Alternatively, you may try to run `regedit.exe` from the command prompt.

```
regedit.exe /S yourfile.reg
```

.. should silently import the reg file. See [RegEdit Command Line Options Syntax](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/82821) for more command line options.

Comment: There shouldn't be any UAC issues, he's writing to HKCU.

Comment: @harry Yeah, correct. For example this one works (homapage change)
REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\INTERNET EXPLORER\MAIN" /V "START PAGE" /D "http://www.ask.com/" /F

Comment: running regedit.exe /S yourfile.reg is a bad idea, since you will not be notified if the there's an error. See answer bellow.

Answer (score 86):

In command line it's better to use **REG** tool rather than REGEDIT:

```
REG IMPORT yourfile.reg
```

REG is designed for console mode, while REGEDIT is for graphical mode.
This is why running ***regedit.exe /S yourfile.reg*** is a bad idea, since you **will not be notified if the there's an error**, whereas REG Tool will prompt:

```
>  REG IMPORT missing_file.reg

ERROR: Error opening the file. There may be a disk or file system error.

>  %windir%\System32\reg.exe /?

REG Operation [Parameter List]

  Operation  [ QUERY   | ADD    | DELETE  | COPY    |
               SAVE    | LOAD   | UNLOAD  | RESTORE |
               COMPARE | EXPORT | IMPORT  | FLAGS ]

Return Code: (Except for REG COMPARE)

  0 - Successful
  1 - Failed

For help on a specific operation type:

  REG Operation /?

Examples:

  REG QUERY /?
  REG ADD /?
  REG DELETE /?
  REG COPY /?
  REG SAVE /?
  REG RESTORE /?
  REG LOAD /?
  REG UNLOAD /?
  REG COMPARE /?
  REG EXPORT /?
  REG IMPORT /?
  REG FLAGS /?
```

Comment: I think the question was how to "Run reg command in cmd (bat file)?". People who search an answer to it, will get here... So I advise them on an alternative way to import registry in CMD. It's definitely better than Regedit.

Answer (score 8):

If memory serves correct, the `reg add` command will NOT create the entire directory path if it does not exist.  Meaning that if any of the parent registry keys do not exist then they must be created manually one by one.  It is really annoying, I know!  **Example:**

```
@echo off
reg add "HKCU\Software\Policies"
reg add "HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft"
reg add "HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer"
reg add "HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Control Panel"
reg add "HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Control Panel" /v HomePage /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
pause
```

Comment: Thanks. But it says "permission denied"

Comment: If it is saying 'permission denied' then the `reg add` needs to be run as an administrator. Also you can most likely remove the first two reg add statements from my example because they should almost always exist.  For a batch method to granting Admin privileges see my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13869544/891976

Comment: The following ran successfully on my Windows XP SP3 machine: `reg add hkcu\software\aaa\aaa /ve /t reg_sz`. Neither of the `aaa`s had existed prior to running the command and both were created with it. So it's more likely a permission issue indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just create a Group Policy Preference and have it create the reg key for you. (no scripting involved)