# How to set value in registry via batch file in Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I am going to set a value to windows registry.
I want to set variable `shit` for `StupidMS` in registry, but the result is wrong. Following is my code.

```
set stupidMS=shit
echo %stupidMS% 

reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "StupidMS" /t REG_SZ /d ^%stupidMS^%
```

I think the problem is **^%stupidMS^%**, but I quite have no idea how to correct it.

Comment: why do yo escape the ***%-s*** ?Try only with `%stupidMS%`

Comment: finally I got it. it should "%stupidMS%". I forget ""

Comment: `"%~stupidMS%"` is safer.

Comment: @ls_dev `%~` doesn't have any special significance to an environment variable and it is invalid syntax.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was thinking about batch arguments.

Comment: Perhaps, it would be better to replace the swearing words with "foo" and "bar".

Comment: +1 für appropriate variable naming

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run reg command in cmd (bat file)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809856/run-reg-command-in-cmd-bat-file)

Comment: There is no need to set "that key" to "that value", They have been using "that" default value since April 4th 1975. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "StupidMS" /t REG_SZ /d "%stupidMS%"
```