# How can I run a batch script after a reboot?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have 2 batch scripts.
This is the first one:

```
pushd \\ta1bbn01\Public\Migration\
      %CD%\uninstallLogs\rationaluninstalltool.exe %CD%\uninstallLogs
      \\%COMPUTERNAME%-%USERNAME%.log -c -nr

    popd
```

The first one is uninstalling a software, then it reboot the machine. After the reboot I want to run my second script which will install a new software.
What should I type in my first script in order to add it to the next start up, I'll need it only for the next start up.
How can I run it within a delay of 30 seconds so I can make sure that all other services are up?

Comment: there's the `RunOnce` registry key for that sort of thing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

put in the batch on the startup folder .. let's assume that your batch is test.bat .. put it in the startup folder

at the end of the batch, check if that everything went right then delete the test.bat

```
@echo off
REM // all your installation logic
REM // if something went wrong exit .. 
REM // we have finished what we want so we will delete the batch from the startup
del test.bat
@echo on
```

I hope this could help.

Comment: What is the path of the installation folder?  Is there any way to do that with the registry if yes please give me some code example .

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714652/how-to-set-value-in-registry-via-batch-file-in-windows