# Need help adding registry key via batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to add the following registry key through cmd. I am not able to get other users to be able to add this registry key using `regedit.exe /s "Location\Project.reg"`.

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Autodesk\Fabrication 2014\Configuration\1011-Shady-Grove]
> "Path"="C:/Autodesk/Profiles/05MA/1011-Shady-Grove"

Comment: All users have admin rights. I have tried to write the code as runas /user:administrator regedit.exe /s "location\Project.reg. I would like to user reg add but not sure of proper coding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run reg command in cmd (bat file)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809856/run-reg-command-in-cmd-bat-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong tool. Regedit is a GUI tool. Yes you can use the /s switch, but fundamentally this is the wrong tool. Plus it is built with the `highestAvailable` option in the UAC manifest.

What you need is `reg`. Use it like this:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Autodesk\Fabrication 2014\Configuration\1011-Shady-Grove" /v Path /d C:/Autodesk/Profiles/05MA/1011-Shady-Grove
```

Comment: Thanks that was what I was wanting help with. I actually got it to work via the following.  reg add "HKCU\Software\Autodesk\Fabrication 2014\Configuration\1011-Shady-Grove" /v Path /t REG_SZ /d C:/Autodesk/Profiles/05MA/1011-Shady-Grove

Comment: /t REG_SZ is the default and can be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, regedit will refuse to do anything if the user doesn't have administrative access, even if he has access to the registry keys.

Try the [reg add](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc742162%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) command.