# Picking a Font For the VBA Editor

Tags: vba, excel

I can easily select a font for a range of cells with something like:

```
Sub PickAFont()
    ActiveCell.Font.Name = "Verdana"
End Sub
```

I need a similar line of code to pick the font used by the *VBA Editor:*

[image]

The macro recorder fails to record the manual selection and Google only returns material on formatting `Ranges`

**EDIT#1:**

I modified *Vityata's* code very slightly:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Application.SendKeys "%TO+{TAB}{RIGHT}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}"
    Application.SendKeys "Verdana {(}Western{)}"
    Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
End Sub
```

and it works on my system.  Changes were needed to handle the German to English menu differences and to handle the font name on my system.

NOTE:  *The macro must be run within VBE environment rather than from the worksheet Ribbon.*

Comment: It is in the registry, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VBA\7.0\Common, so google how to set the registry entry

Comment: Echo @Nathan_Sav comments. I checked around the VBIDE library and don't see anything useful in there, so it seems to be a registry edit that's required.

Comment: Interesting question, but why would you want to do this by code? Only coders see the editor, why not let coders chose it for themselves?

Comment: Plus it needs to reload before you see the effects and it's under current user in the registry, so would be coder to coder dependant anyhow

Comment: @JohnColeman  When I begin working on a new machine, I typically configure both Excel and the VBE to my preferences.  I am currently doing this manually using a paper checklist...........I would like to automate this manual process................I can do the Excel options programmatically...........not so much the VBE options !

Comment: Your preference is to code in a non-monospace font? ;-)

Comment: Seems like a good reason. I was just curious.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310516 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667500/need-help-adding-registry-key-via-batch-file

Comment: you could export the registry entry and take that with you from machine to machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something very simple, but it works:

```
Option Explicit
'https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821075.aspx

Sub SetFont()

    Application.VBE.ScreenUpdating = False

    Application.SendKeys "%XO+{TAB}{RIGHT}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}"
    Application.SendKeys "VERANDA"
    Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

    Application.VBE.ScreenUpdating = true

End Sub
```

(I am with a German VBE, you should probably change the sendkeys to English one). But it selects Veranda. :)

Comment: Don't you wish you could do `Application.VBE.ScreenUpdating = False` while popping up the settings dialog =)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code. At home I am with English layout, will use it there! :)