# Manipulate registry settings on a Win CE 7 System with a Batch file

Tags: batch-file, windows-ce, regedit

I got a problem with manipulating my registry settings. I use a Panel PC with windows embedded compact version 7 (Win Ce). I want change the display-brightness, which is set on "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ControlPanel\BackLight", by a BAT file. I use following syntax:

reg add "HKCU\ControlPanel\BackLight" /T REG_DWORD /F /D 150 /V ACBacklightLevel

But when I run the file, the error message : "Cannot execute reg.exe"

I tried the Bat File on my PC with windows 7. It works correctly.

Is there a problem with the command "reg add" on Win CE systems? Did i make another mistake?

Thanks in advance

- Frank

edit:

I´m not sure if this is important, but I use in the header of my BAT file the line "REGEDIT4". I read in other forum that it is for WIN98, NT and 4.0. But there isn´t any command fpr windows CE. Do you know what it does?

edit 23.04.2015:

I created a .reg file, which increases the brightness of my HMI. It worked when I import it manually. Is it possible to import it automatically via Batch file or something like that? someone know the syntax of this command or got another idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

the correct command line is (you must use the cmd):

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\BackLight" /v  "ACBacklightLevel" /t REG_DWORD /d 150 /f
```

for the next time:

```
REG ADD "Register key name"  /v "key name" /t "type" /d "type value" /f
```

Comment: @ Odinino:Thanks for your fast answer. I copied the line, but the error "Cannot execute REG.exe" appears again. I read that the first line of every BAT file has to begin with "REGEDIT4". Is that correct?

Comment: @FrankBiermann
I had misunderstood the request.
If you use REGEDIT4, you want create a .reg file.
The line in a .reg file is (I think is right):

`code`
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\BackLight]
"ACBacklightLevel"=dword:00000096

where 00000096 is 150 in hex.

The file .reg will:
`code`
REGEDIT4
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\BackLight] "ACBacklightLevel"=dword:00000096

I think is necessary only one REGEDIT4 in the first line.

the REG ADD is used for the .cmd file
Try to copy and use the REG ADD line in the command prompt and look what happens (to see if it works).

Comment: I tried it with the command prompt and the result was the same "Cannot execute reg. exe". I think the command is unknown on Win CE. The other option, to create a new .reg file with  "REGEDIT4" is the same "Cannot execute REGEDIT.exe". I think to change the settings with files or over command prompts is not possible with my CE version. Or the Syntax is another one.

Comment: I found these links: [blogs.msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehall/archive/2005/03/23/401348.aspx),
[stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809856/run-reg-command-in-cmd-bat-file)

I hope you can be useful.
Other ideas and solutions do not come to mind, sorry