# Add start up reg key without run the program

Tags: registrykey

I coded a program, which start up on windows start up. My code is this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        RegistryKey reg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", true);//kanei autostart to programma sto anoigma tou upologisti
        public Form1()
        {
            reg.SetValue("Computer Integrity", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());//computer integrity is the reg key name
            reg.Close();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Now, the problem is that in order for the program to start, in windows start up, needs to open it first so the key will be registered in the  "Registry editor". Is there a way to create a file(.bat for example) in order to register this key to the "registry editor", without needing to open the program ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create the key in regisgry manually and then just export to *yourfile.reg* file:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755091.aspx
Then you can run the regedit from a command line:

```
regedit.exe /S yourfile.reg
```

You can also run such a commands from batch file directly via REG ADD command. 
Refer here for details: [Run reg command in cmd (bat file)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809856/run-reg-command-in-cmd-bat-file)